# Repository pattern and inheritance in .net

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, inheritance, repository-pattern

i am pretty new to the repository design pattern and i have reached a dead end while trying to implement it, with regards to inheritance.

I am not sure even if i started in the right direction.

So basically i will have an abstract base class Product, with id and imagePath for instance, and will have several products which inherit from this.

```
namespace Common
{
    public abstract class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ImgPath { get; set; }
    }

    public class Scale : Product
    {
        public int AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now the repositories are as follows:

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    protected TEstEntities1 _dataContext = new TEstEntities1();

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        _dataContext = new TEstEntities1();
    }
}

public interface IProductRepository 
{
    Common.Product Get(int id);
    void Add(Common.Product p);
    void Update(Common.Product p);
    List<Common.Product> ListAll();
}

public class ProductRepository : BaseRepository, IProductRepository
{
    public Common.Product Get(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Add(Common.Product p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(Common.Product p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public List<Common.Product> ListAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My problem is as follows: how do i integrate operations regarding Scale ? It seems a bad idea to add something like Add(Common.Scale s) to the IProductRepository. It seems like a bad idea to see inside the Add(Common.Product p) which type of Product i try to add, then cast to it, then add.

I guess that if i were to describe this problem more thoroughly, I want to repeat as few code as possible, to somehow isolate base product adding/removing code in the product repository, and somehow put e.g. Scale specific code for adding/removing inside another class, or method.

A more thorough approach of mine has been this one:

```
public interface IProductRepository<T> where T : Common.Product
{
    T Get(int id);
    void Add(T p);
    void Delete(T p);
}

public abstract class ProductRepository : BaseRepository
{
    protected void Add(Common.Product p)
    {
        _dataContext.AddToProduct(new Product { Id = p.Id, Image = p.ImgPath });
        _dataContext.AcceptAllChanges();
    }

    protected void Delete(Common.Product p)
    {
        var c = _dataContext.Product.Where(x => x.Id == p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        _dataContext.DeleteObject(c);
        _dataContext.AcceptAllChanges();
    }

    protected Product Get(int id)
    {
        return _dataContext.Product.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public class CantarRepository : ProductRepository, IProductRepository<Common.Scale>
{
    public void Add(Common.Scale p)
    {
        base.Add(p);
        _dataContext.Scale.AddObject
             (new Scale { ProductId = p.Id, AdditionalProperty = p.AdditionalProperty });
        _dataContext.AcceptAllChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(Common.Scale p)
    {
        var c = _dataContext.Scale.Where(x => x.ProductId == p.Id);
        _dataContext.DeleteObject(c);
        _dataContext.AcceptAllChanges();
        base.Delete(p);
    }

    public new Common.Scale Get(int id)
    {
        var p = base.Get(id);
        return new Common.Scale
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            ImgPath = p.Image,
            AdditionalProperty = _dataContext.Scale.Where
               (c => c.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault().AdditionalProperty
        };
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly this falls short for one reason.
If i use a factory pattern to return an IProductRepository and inside it i instantiate with IProductRepository this will not work because of covariance and contravariance, and IProductRepository can't be contravariant and covariant at the same time, and splitting the methods into two interfaces seems counterintuitive and cumbersome.

I suspect i will need the factory pattern in order to have a base class interface returned, but i am open to suggestions on this as well. As i've said, i am very newbie regarding the repo pattern.

I am curious as to what i am doing wrong, how i can solve this, and how can i implement this better.

Thanks.

Comment: Here are a couple of useful links on this issue: http://devtalk.dk/2009/06/09/Entity+Framework+40+Beta+1+POCO+ObjectSet+Repository+And+UnitOfWork.aspx http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/06/21/revisiting-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Don#'t say pattern. Say antipattern. Your patterns willfully brutally abuse what entity framework has to offer.

Answer (score 4):

You are using inheritance incorrectly. You cannot treat Scale as a (is-a) Product if the important difference is additional properties - that makes the exposed interface of Scale different than Product, and at that point inheritance simply gets in your way.  Use inheritance to share *behavior*, not *properties*.

What problem are you trying to solve with your use of inheritance?

> I want to repeat as few code as
>   possible

Wouldn't it be better to have a little duplication in order to get things done, rather than spin your wheels trying to work with an implausible design?

Also, this is all you are sharing with your inheritance:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImgPath { get; set; }
```

Repeating the definition of two auto-implemented properties almost doesn't even qualify as duplication, it most certainly is not an issue to be concerned about.

**Misusing inheritance, however, is fairly grievous.**  The next person to maintain your app will curse you for it.

> So basically i will have an abstract
>   base class Product, with id and
>   imagePath for instance, and will have
>   several products which inherit from
>   this.

So when you add new types of products you will have to extend an inheritance hierarchy? That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I've given this some more thought and let's say i have a service request, in which someone brings a scale or a cash register to be repaired. If i don't use inheritance how am i supposed to model this ?It seems counterintiutive to have two members inside my Service class - CashRegister cashRegisterToBeServiced (which will be null if a cash register will not be repaired), and Scale scaleToBeServiced (which again might be null). I have to somehow derive them from a base class/interface (maybe an interface IInventory with a serial number) to have a correct structure. Your thoughts on this please ?

Comment: "If i don't use inheritance how am i supposed to model this?" Well, you don't really give enough info here.  Could go many different ways, but you are right that having two members in your service class, one for register one for scale, is counter intuitive.  I would never recommend that nor should it ever be necessary.

Comment: imho, you should spend more time *explicitly* defining what you need to do with "products" that needs to process registers and scales together. There needs to be enough benefit to dealing with these commonly to outweigh the complexity involved by coupling registers and scales through either a base class or a common interface (and almost always preferring the latter because it is often enough and often the less complex solution).

Comment: Stab in the dark: I might model a ServiceRequest specifically as its own entity and perhaps do serviceRequest.AddProduct(myProduct), where myProduct implements some interface, but use method overloads where the specific product type requires special or additional logic. Again, there's a huge lack of detail here, but I still say it's obvious that you are misusing the type system in a way that is needlessly introducing complexity and that is heading towards serious trouble.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a big fan of generic repository but after looking at your code I think you should use it:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity 
{
    IQueryable<T> GetQuery();
    T Get(int id);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
}
```

implementation:

```
public Repository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    private ObjectSet<T> _set;          // or DbSet
    private ObjectContext _context;  // or DbContext

    public Repository(ObjectContext context) // or DbContext
    {
        _context = context;
        _set = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();  // _context.Set<T>() for DbContext                     
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetQuery()
    {
        return _set;
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return _set.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    public void Add (T entity)
    {
        _set.AddObject(entity);
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        _set.Attach(entity);
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
        // or context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; for DbContext
    }

    public void Delete(entity)
    {
        _set.Attach(entity);
        _set.DeleteObject(entity);
    }
}
```

There is **NO AcceptAllChanges** because it will reset `ObjectStateManager` and your changes will never be saved. There is no recreation of objects because it doesn't make sense.

Using this repository is as simple as:

```
var repo = new BaseRepository<Product>(context);
repo.Add(new Product() { ... });
repo.Add(new Scale() { ... }); // yes this works because derived entities are handled by the same set
context.Save();
```

Comment: Woah there! Entities should not expose their ids!!

Comment: @Domenic: Yes I read it also. It is nice theory but using it in real world - especially with EF is imho impractical but I if you have any article or idea how to do it post it either as comment or separate answer.

Comment: @Domenic: I'm of the opinion that the id is the **only** property an entity should expose.  No other data, only behavior. Data is to be encapsulated.

Comment: @qes: So in your domain entities don't have properties, just behavior? It's weird to imagine a person without a first name, but maybe that's just me...

Comment: @Domenic: Lately I've been using domains *only* for modifications.  I do not query through my domain.  There are a large number of benefits to be gained from architecturally separating reads from writes (CQRS).  Person's have first names, but there is no need to expose that as a public property of a domain object.

Comment: Frankly, most systems I've seen that expose properties (even moreso if those properties expose public setters) are little more than architecturally glorified DALs with **lots** of tight coupling.

Comment: @qes: Fair enough, if you are doing CQRS. I don't know enough about it to be sure, but I personally find it misleading to use terminology like "domain entities" when really you're talking about the command side of a CQRS architecture.

Comment: @Domenic: I do feel there can be confusion with DDD terms, given the variety of implementations seen. But if I do something like `var acct = aRepo.Get(acctId); var pkg = pRepo.Get(pkgId); acct.SubscribeTo(pkg);` I do consider those domain entities, even if they are only ever touched inside a command handler and expose only methods.

Comment: I disagree with having an interface slapped onto a domain model. Unless you are planning on swapping out your domain model (which would mean the business behavior has completely changed), you shouldn't be associating an interface to a domain model (for business apps, which this model looks like it could be). OO principles shouldn't be bent to accommodate ORMs.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented something like this. (Using your sample types names) I have a single `ProductRepository` which knows how to persist/unpersist all `Product` subtypes.

Ultimately, your backing data store will have to have the ability to store the various subtypes and any properties which they introduce. Your repository type will also have to know how to take advantage of those features for each given subtype. Therefore, each time you add a subtype, you will have work involved in, for example, adding table columns to your backing data store to hold properties it may introduce. This implies that you will also need to make the appropriate changes to your repository type. It seems easiest, therefore, to examine the type of the entity when passed to your repository type and throw an exception if it is not a supported type since there's nothing else your repository will be able to do with it. Similarly, when retrieving the list of entities, the repository will have to know how to retrieve each entity subtype and construct an instance. Since these all derive from `Product`, they can all form items an in `IEnumerable<Product>` return value.